# LaTeX complains that \tkzDrawArc is not defined

Tags: tkz-euclide

I'm trying to draw an arc between two points, centered at a third.  I thought the following example should work

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.5]
  \tkzDefPoint(0,0){O}
  \tkzDefPoint(2,-1){A}
  \tkzDefPoint(1,1){B}
  \tkzDrawArc[color=blue](O,A)(B)
  \tkzDrawArc[color=Maroon](O,B)(A)
  \tkzDrawArc(O,B)(A)
  \tkzDrawLines[add = 0 and .5](O,A O,B)
  \tkzDrawPoints(O,A,B)
  \tkzLabelPoints[below](O,A,B)
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

instead I get an error message that `\tkzDrawArc` is an undefined control sequence.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to add the line

```
\usetkzobj{all}
```

to your preamble straight after `\usepackage{tkz-euclide}`.
From the README in the [CTAN entry for `tkz-euclide`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/tkz/tkz-euclide):

> To use the package `tkz-euclide`, place the following lines in the preamble of
>    your LaTeX document.
>
> ```
> \usepackage{tkz-euclide} 
> \usetkzobj{all}
> ```
>
> `\usepackage{tkz-euclide}` loads `tkz-base` and TikZ. `\usetkzobj{all}` loads all
>    objects used by `tkz-euclide`.

You’ll get a second error from the `Maroon` colour which isn’t defined yet; add the line

```
\usepackage[usenames, dvipsnames]{xcolor}
```

*before* you load `tkz-euclide` to get that colour.